# Show plots with pygal

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygal

I want to try plots with [pygal](http://pygal.org/); however, when I do `render` nothing appears:

```
xy_chart = pygal.XY()
xy_chart.add('test', [(1,2), (2,2)])
xy_chart.render('test.svg')
```

Presumably, that's because the format is svg. Can I somehow save the images in standard formats or see them in python using pygal?

I tried to install dependencies for png support, but unfortunately each package requires additional installment of other packages, which eventually leads to errors.

Comment: What do you mean by *nothing appears*? `render` is supposed to write a file to disk. To simply view the svg file, open it with a browser. If you can't install png support directly, you can always use other software to convert the svg file to a png afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

replace the last line with this:

```
xy_chart.render_to_file('test.svg')
```

render() returns a string, but it doesn't write a file directly. Try doing this to see what I mean:

```
svg_content = xy_chart.render()
f = open('test.svg', 'w')
print >> f, svg_content
f.close()
```